# Why is the rough plumbing for a urinal so expensive?

Tags: plumbing

When I built my house 7 years ago, I had them rough in a drain in the basement bathroom for a future urinal (which is in now).  After the fact, I found out this was like a $1500 addition.

My brother is building right now and got a similar quote.  Why is it so expensive?  In both situations, the urinal is "in line" with the sink and toilet drain line which is vented.  Seems it's a matter of $20 of PVC and some minor labor to install a T fitting...what am I missing?  Even it is was a separate drain line, it's about 10ft from the main drain stack/lift pump, and exposed (pre-concrete).

Also - neither of those quotes was for running the supply line, providing the urinal, or installing it.  Just to rough plumb additional drain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the pricing of a job.

Comment: I think that it could be overhauled to simply ask what is required to rough in the urinal as long as all mention of costs/prices were dropped.

Comment: @KevinV, please edit the question - I'd like to know what goes into a urinal install.